# my spring boot webapp.war stop running on ssh logout. how to create app service so it runs without user logged in

Tags: spring, ubuntu, service, deployment, war

my spring boot webapp.war stop running on ssh logout. So i tried to create my own service using $ sudo ln -s /path/to/webapp.war /etc/init.d/webapp and then $ sudo service webapp start. but it says  "Failed to start webapp.service: Unit webapp.service not found." I am using ubuntu 16.04. i am logged in as non root user

Answer (score 0):

If the war application doesn't have an embedded servlet container, the app would have to be deployed to one first (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow) or to a app server (Weblogic, ...).

To run the servlet container as a Linux service, one of the options is [Tanuki Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)